# Facing issue while redirecting to page in serveResource: liferay

Tags: liferay, liferay-6

I am facing issue while redirecting to another page in serveResource method.
I got following exception

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Config is null, please ensure that your init(config) method calls super.init(config)
```

Following is my serveResource method

```
public void serveResource(ResourceRequest resourceRequest, ResourceResponse resourceResponse) throws PortletException {


        System.out.println("Serve Resource Method Called");


        try {

            String url = getURL(Long.valueOf(resourceRequest.getParameter("key")));
            resourceRequest.setAttribute("url", conn.getURL().toString());
        include("/html/viewImage.jsp", resourceRequest, resourceResponse);
} catch (Exception e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

How to solve this problem?

Thanks

Comment: Does your portlet have an init method? If yes - please post it as well

Comment: no portlet hasn't any init method

Comment: This error occurred while calling my serveResource method from another portlet...

Answer (score 0):

According to your comment you're calling `serveResource` from a different portlet. You're not supposed to do that.

If you share an implementation between different portlets, separate it out into a common component. You have no business in calling lifecycle methods yourself. Further, you probably are instantiating that portlet class yourself (otherwise there'd be no object to call `serveResource` on), which will probably not call `init()` at all - and here we are again: It's the portal's business to call lifecycle functions, not yours.

Comment: Ok..Thanks for reply..But i want to redirect to another page in serveResource method..How can i do that?

Comment: redirect as in HTTP-redirect (e.g. sending status-code-302 responses) or as in showing different content?

Comment: redirect to another jsp page.. "/html/viewImage.jsp"

Comment: on this "/html/viewImage.jsp" page. I just send the url in parameter and showing an image

Answer (score 0):

If we talk about jsp-servlet , we can switch from one jsp to another by two way only.

1) SendRedirect 
2) Forward page

If we talk about pure servlet then for forwarding page would be like as below:

```
RequestDispatcher dispatcher = request.getRequestDispatcher("/template.jsp");
if (dispatcher != null) dispatcher.forward(request, response);
```

Now in order to answer of your question.
Portlet JSR 286 has created one interface for portlets on top of the RequestDisptcher, which will generate dispatcher reference.
below code has meaning as above describe.

```
PortletRequestDispatcher dispatcher = resourceRequest.getPortletSession().getPortletContext().getRequestDispatcher("/html/viewImage.jsp");
dispatcher.forward(resourceRequest, resourceResponse);
```

[reference](https://www.liferay.com/community/forums/-/message_boards/message/5877288)

HTH!

Thanks.

Comment: You should add some information, why this is an answer to the question.

Comment: Right! but i guess the code is self explanatory and remaining explanation is being already given in earlier answer.

Comment: An earlier answer is not necessarily shown before a later one - the order my change due to votes or activity. And I have to admit that I don't see the connection to Olafs answer or why this is the correct answer to the question...

Comment: I didn't say that there is any connection between the answers, but there is some explanation in context to Question that has already been provided, repeating which I don't think, is good.